# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm new in pygame and I have that error please help me.

```
    backgrounf_image_filename = 'ubisoft.jpg'
    mouse_image_filename = 'cursor.png'

    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    from sys import exit

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!")
    background = pygame.image.load(backgrounf_image_filename).convert()
    mouse_cursor = pygame.image(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()
```

and I have that error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/ziyaa/PycharmProjects/pygame/helloworld.py", line 13, in <module>
        mouse_cursor = pygame.image(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: first post and full stacktrace included: that well deserves an upvote, and an answer :)

Comment: as someone noted, your indentation is a bit off in the end. You may encounter issues (but it's irrelevant to the question, I'll edit that out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing:

```
background = pygame.image.load(backgrounf_image_filename).convert()
mouse_cursor = pygame.image(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()
```

In the second instruction, you forgot to `load` your image, resulting in calling the module instead of the function.

Just do:

```
mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(mouse_image_filename).convert_alpha()
```

Comment: didn't load how? crash? nothing shown? where are the images located?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your for event.get loop. I use a similar one for my games, and its the right approach however you have your next few lines indented wrong

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x -= mouse_cursor.get_width()/2
        y -= mouse_cursor.get_height()/2
        screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))
```

needs to be unidented or moved back

Comment: that's not the issue, that may be the OP _next_ issue though.

Comment: that's because you have an english backgrounf.